# Is a semicolon or colon needed after "including"?

Tags: semicolons, colons

Previous research has identified four individual factors which appear to predict this including**;** need to feel loved, need to be loved and self-esteem.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: I would use either nothing (for a short list) or a colon and dash (for a longer list). But why mention four factors and list only three, two of which are nearly identical?

Comment: Use a colon after **include**; do not use anything after **including**.

Comment: Thank you! I inadvertently typed four instead of three. And you're right, two of the factors listed are nearly identical. Thanks for the suggestion.